# Which jdbc driver is used for java 1.6?

Tags: java, jdbc

Im getting an error when i start a process in intalio server:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.UnsupportedException:Java Runtime Environment
>       JRE 1.6 is not supported by this driver.Use sqljdbc4 class library which supports JDBC 4.

I have used the java version:1.6 and have used sqljdbc4

Can anybody tell me why Im getting this Exception?

Comment: what database software are you connecting to?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a conflicting class path entry that is loading the unsupported driver?

Comment: It's probably MS SQL Server, because as far as I know that's the only JDBC driver that doesn't allow you to run in a newer JRE. All other drivers silently accept it and work (with the reduced functionality, of course).

Comment: Please contact Intalio's support. We can help.

Answer (score 1):

The server might have an older version of the JAR that the class loader is picking up before it ever gets to your sqljdbc4.jar.

Either remove the older JAR if you can or tell the server to prefer JARs that it finds in your application deployment.